# How to prevent licensed video/document sharing?

Tags: blocking, sharing

If a website is to provide non-free content in terms of videos and documents, how is one about to serve this kind of content? I don't want to write an occasionally connected desktop application (similar to iTunes) that prevents to easily share bought content so I have a few questions about this:

1. **Documents**: What's best document format for this kind of scenario that would prevent one to share it freely after it was bought?

   If I think of PDF it's a great format so people can't temper with its content and they will actually see what you created, but the problem is that after one obtains it, it can easily get shared with others. Either having password or not.
2. **Videos**: If supporting video it's probably wise to use some public (may be payable as well) service that can handle video streaming like YouTube (which is AFAIK not able to have a non-public videos).

I'm well aware that there is no 100% perfect solution that prevents it all, but having a 90% successfully locked down content is still better than hoping people won't share something that can easily be shared.

Can you list a few websites that do a similar thing. I may learn a lot from them. And please provide some guidelines I should follow in this regard.

**Is there maybe a similar to PDF document format that has built in security capabilities? Commercial even...** It should support some kind of authorization functionality within that would work similarly to any software activation.

> ***Note:** I wasn't sure whether this should be posted on webapps.stackexchange.com or here but I decided it should be posted here because it's related to development. I'm generally interested in programmable approaches I could use.*

Comment: Great question. For PDFs I would dynamically personalize content (like subscriptionId in commentts) and encrypt pdf to prevent modifications. If document leaks, you can easily indentify the user.

Comment: @Matej: That's what crossed my mind as well because few years ago I did see the same strategy applied to a digital book in PDF format a friend of mine bought. **But** is there a better way? This protection is more or less *good will*.